# Liferay - change portlet column programmatically

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I'm doing a Liferay portal with different portlets on it in different columns created in a Liferay Layout.

My question is: How can I change programmatically (in java) the column to which a portlet belongs?

I've tried with this:

```
long userId = themeDisplay.getUserId();
long groupId = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId();

Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLLayout(groupId, true, currentFriendlyURL);
LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = (LayoutTypePortlet) layout.getLayoutType();

layoutTypePortlet.removePortletId(userId, iniPortletName);
String portletInstanceId = layoutTypePortlet.addPortletId(userId, iniPortletName, newColumn, position, true);

LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(layout.getGroupId(), layout.isPrivateLayout(), layout.getLayoutId(), layout.getTypeSettings());
```

It works, but with this code, I delete the portlet and then, I create a new instance, and I don't want that.

How can I update the position of **same** instance of the portlet?

Thank you.

Comment: I flagged as too broad. While you as a question, you are just asking if XYZ is possible. It likely is. Do you have any code to show us? Any error messages? What have you tried? (Not just theorized to work)

Comment: I'm sorry. I hope it is now clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

If you want to keep the same instance, you can use the *movePortletId(userId, portletId, newColumn, position)* method.

```
String portletId = (String) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_ID);
layoutTypePortlet.movePortletId(userId, portletId, finColumn, position);
```

You need to use the portletId instead of portletName, that identifies all the portlets with the same name.

https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/portal/model/LayoutTypePortlet.html

Thank you.